# Parameterised datatype as a module parameter?

Tags: parameters, module, agda, algebraic-data-types, mutual-recursion

In Agda, how can I define a parameterised module equivalent to the following?

```
data Sig : Set ℓ where
  ■ : Sort → Sig
  ν : Sig → Sig

module SortedABT {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) (Op : Sort → Set ℓ) (sig : (s : Sort) → Op s → List Sig) where
```

Of course the above doesn't work because `ℓ` and `Sort` appear in the definition of `Sig`, but are parameters of the module, so not yet defined where they appear. I've looked at the Agda manual and tried various web searches, but not found a workaround. Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of UX you're looking for, but you could try

```
module _ {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) where

  data Sig : Set ℓ where
    ■ : Sort → Sig
    ν : Sig → Sig

  module SortedABT (Op : Sort → Set ℓ) (sig : (s : Sort) → Op s → List Sig) where
```

That adds

```
Sig : ∀ {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) → Set ℓ
```

to the current scope together with the expected `SortedABT`.

Alternatively you may want to give the outer `module` a name like this:

```
module SigAndStuff {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) where
```

so that it always needs to be `open`ed explicitly at a specific `Sort`, e.g.

```
open SigAndStuff ⊤
```

which adds

```
Sig : Set
```

to the current scope as well as your original `SortedABT` instantiated like this:

```
SortedABT {zero} {⊤}
```

Comment: Another solution was provided by

Answer (score 0):

Another answer was provided by Naïm Camille Favier on the Agda Zulip.

```
data Sig {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) : Set ℓ where
  ■ : Sort → Sig Sort
  ν : Sig Sort → Sig Sort

module SortedABT {ℓ} (Sort : Set ℓ) (Op : Sort → Set ℓ) (sig : (s : Sort) → Op s → List (Sig Sort)) where
...
```